# Can one get hardware quotations by hardware features online?

Tags: motherboard, networking, ssd, server, network-adapter

I'm looking for the simplest motherboard with an i7 processor, one RAM slot for 16gb, 10G RDMA NIC, 1 SATA port, a small NVME and power supply. No need for display ports, USB ports , KVM ports, multimedia ports etc. I'm looking for the cheapest option to build a 2-node Hyper converged Hyper-V Cluster on Nano Server 2016 with storage space direct.

Comment: http://pcpartpicker.com